# How to dismiss alertview in delegate function - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview, dismiss

In my app, I need to dismiss the alertview when user click the button in alertview.
I tried `[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:NO];`in my app, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do nothing.

> The alert view is automatically dismissed after the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method is invoked.

From the [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAlertViewDelegate).

What makes you think you need to dismiss the alert? Are you perhaps presenting many identical UIAlertViews?

Comment: After I click the button, I need to do some data analyze, which could take some time, while I don't like the user to wait there for dismissing the alertview.
That's my intention.

Comment: Then you need to stop doing that work on the main thread so that you stop blocking the UI.

Comment: You have several options including NSObject's `-performSelectorInBackground:` or GCD operations or `dispatch_async` calls to execute NSOperations or blocks on an appropriate queue. Many other questions here cover those and Apple provides http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html. Which one you should use depends on the work you need done, how you can parallelize it, and how you need to communicate results when it is finished.